# can I skip row version update in sql?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, t-sql

I am using sql row version colum for optimistic concurrency.
but I have one senario that I dont want the row version to be updated.

I mean that I want update the table row but keep the old value ov the row version.

is it possible?

Comment: You cannot do this - SQL Server will update the rowversion on **every** update of the row. No way to turn this off or circumvent it - it just happens every time you update the row.

Comment: @marc_s is absolutely right, you cannot get around the built in rowversion data-type.

Answer (score 0):

marc_s is right in the comments above - you cannot work around the built in SQL Server rowversion.

You can get around row version changes if you implement a home grown row versioning / e-tag solution and in such circumstances you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method

```
context.Database.SqlQuery()
```

or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679456%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()
```

to affect data outside of EF